# world time api in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

This is the part of the flutter application. this application is shows the time of the city

the error happen in the url of the api

```
Response response = await get(Uri.http('http://worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi'));
```

The error massage is this
**Invalid radix-10 number**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

Map data;

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  getData() async {
    Response response = await get(
        Uri.http('http://worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi'));
    print(response.body);
    await (data = jsonDecode(response.body));
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('the data will on second hot restart like on ctrl+s'),
                  ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `http://` from URL. =>  `Uri.http('worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi')`

Comment: Please copy paste the full error message.

Comment: this is the full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include the protocol in the authority string of the `Uri.http` constructor.

```dart
Response response = await get(Uri.http('worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi'));
```